# Get current time in milliseconds, or HH:MM:SS:MMM format

Tags: c++, date

I've written a c++ function to get the current time in `HH:MM:SS` format. How can I add milliseconds or nanoseconds, so I can have a format like `HH:MM:SS:MMM`? If not possible, a function that returns current time in ms would also be good. I can then calculate the relative time distances between two log points myself.

```
string get_time()
{
    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
    std::stringstream sstm;
    sstm << (now->tm_hour) << ':' << (now->tm_min) << ':' << now->tm_sec;
    string s = sstm.str();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: `std::put_time` has `%T` for HH:MM:SS.

Comment: _'... add milliseconds or nanoseconds ...'_ Huh! That's a big dimension range! Pick one :P ...

Comment: Well, since I have a ping client, and on bash shell we only can access ns! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a cleaner solution using HowardHinnant's [date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library.

```
std::string get_time()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
    return date::format("%T", now);
}
```

Answer (score 58):

This is a portable method using the `C++11` chrono library:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// ...

std::string time_in_HH_MM_SS_MMM()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    // get current time
    auto now = system_clock::now();

    // get number of milliseconds for the current second
    // (remainder after division into seconds)
    auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()) % 1000;

    // convert to std::time_t in order to convert to std::tm (broken time)
    auto timer = system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    // convert to broken time
    std::tm bt = *std::localtime(&timer);

    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << std::put_time(&bt, "%H:%M:%S"); // HH:MM:SS
    oss << '.' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << ms.count();

    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: Really?  You get 3 digits of milliseconds?

Comment: This solution is almost portable. However, not every OS supports every conversion specifier. On my Windows 7 machine I get the error `"Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function."` when trying to use specifiers like `%F` and `%T`. I had to replace them with `%Y-%m-%d` and `%H:%M:%S`, respectively.

Comment: @Sebastian It should be portable between `C++11` compliant compilers. Is your compiler fairly old? Maybe it has an incomplete `C++11` implementation? I made the change in the code so it will work for more people, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The compiler is new:
`$ g++ --version
g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`
It's the runtime that's causing the problems. If I have time I'll look into it more, but for now it's working for me without the aggregate format code like `%F` and `%T`.

Comment: Just a warning if you are stuck on GCC 4 like I am:
`std::put_time` wasn't implemented before GCC 5.

Answer (score 2):

For windows maybe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

int main()
{
    CHAR sysTimeStr[13] = {};
    SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
    GetLocalTime(&systemTime);
    sprintf_s(sysTimeStr,
        "%u:%02u:%02u:%03u",
        systemTime.wHour,
        systemTime.wMinute,
        systemTime.wSecond,
        systemTime.wMilliseconds);

    std::cout << sysTimeStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `time()` (seconds since the epoch), try `gettimeofday()`.  Gives you a structure that includes a microseconds field.

Comment: Or use `<chrono>` in C++11.

Comment: Note that `gettimeofday` is a POSIX function and not standard C++. This solution is not portable to non-POSIX systems; in general, the C++11 approach from the other answer should be preferred.