# How convert string to datetime c++?

Tags: c++, string, time

```
string s = v[2];

        string result = s.substr(s.find_last_of("modify=") + 1, 14);

        cout << result;//output MDTM boost.txt 20150911115551
```

i want convert like this  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

Comment: http://arsenmk.blogspot.com.tr/2014/07/converting-string-to-datetime-and-vice.html you can find solution here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281293/timestamps-for-embedded-system or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686846/get-current-time-in-milliseconds-or-hhmmssmmm-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access date and time related functions and structures, you would need to include  header file in your C++ program.

There are four time-related types: clock_t, time_t, size_t, and tm. The types clock_t, size_t and time_t are capable of representing the system time and date as some sort of integer.

The structure type tm holds the date and time in the form of a C structure having the following elements:

```
struct tm {
  int tm_sec;   // seconds of minutes from 0 to 61
  int tm_min;   // minutes of hour from 0 to 59
  int tm_hour;  // hours of day from 0 to 24
  int tm_mday;  // day of month from 1 to 31
  int tm_mon;   // month of year from 0 to 11
  int tm_year;  // year since 1900
  int tm_wday;  // days since sunday
  int tm_yday;  // days since January 1st
  int tm_isdst; // hours of daylight savings time
}
```

Considering that you have the data string in the following format "YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", the subsequent code below show how to convert the string in a date structure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char date[] = "2012-05-06 21:47:59";
    tm *ltm = new tm;

    char* pch;
    pch = strtok(date, " ,.-:");
    ltm->tm_year = atoi(pch); //get the year value
    ltm->tm_mon = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ,.-:"));  //get the month value
    ltm->tm_mday = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ,.-:")); //get the day value
    ltm->tm_hour = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ,.-:")); //get the hour value
    ltm->tm_min = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ,.-:")); //get the min value
    ltm->tm_sec = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ,.-:")); //get the sec value

    // print various components of tm structure.
    cout << "Year: "<< ltm->tm_year << endl;
    cout << "Month: "<< ltm->tm_mon<< endl;
    cout << "Day: "<< ltm->tm_mday << endl;
    cout << "Time: "<< ltm->tm_hour << ":";
    cout << ltm->tm_min << ":";
    cout << ltm->tm_sec << endl;

    delete ltm;
    return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
Year: 2012
Month: 5
Day: 6
Time: 21:47:59
```