# Outputting date in ISO 8601 format

Tags: c++

How can I get a date in the following format in C++:

```
2016-04-26T19:50:48Z

#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

time_t _tm = time(NULL);
struct tm*curtime = localtime(&_tm);
```

And outputting as `asctime(curtime)`

The current output is:  `"Thu Apr 28 16:02:41 2016\n"`

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime

Comment: No research effort in evidence = downvote

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26896792/1599699

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) is your friend:

```
std::time_t t
    = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
std::cout << std::put_time( std::localtime( &t ), "%FT%T%z" );
```

in my system yields

```
2016-04-29T02:48:56+0200
```

Comment: Do you know how to display the millisecond part of the timestamp?

Comment: @aviggiano I don't think the millisecond part is part of the ISO 8601 format, so that would be a new question.

Comment: I have to disagree (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times and especially the last paragraph there). Basically, you can put a decimal fraction part behind any of the time components, but it must be the last given. For millisecond precision it would be something like `2019-06-18T18:12:34.456` (or comma instead of decimal point), but the `put_time()` method doesn't seem to support a format specifier for the millisecond part. One solution that helped me, was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157784/5823275.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Uri's answer which fixes a few bugs and shows the time in the proper timezone along with the milliseconds in ISO8601 format:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::tm* now_tm = std::localtime(&time);
long long timestamp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();

std::cout << std::setfill('0') 
          << std::put_time(now_tm, "%FT%H:%M:")
          << std::setw(2) << (timestamp / 1000) % 60 << '.'
          << std::setw(3) << timestamp % 1000
          << std::put_time(now_tm, "%z");
```

Comment: Note that std::localtime may not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm combining the `std::localtime` which gives me calendar values, with `std::chrono` functions that gives me the precise methods. Here is my code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

...

auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now)
auto now_tm = std::localtime(&now_c);
auto now_since_epoch = now.time_since_epoch();    // since 1970
auto now_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now_since_epoch).count();

std::cout << std::setfill('0') <<
    std::setw(4) << now_tm->tm_year + 1900 << '-' <<
    std::setw(2) << now_tm->tm_mon + 1 << '-' <<
    std::setw(2) << now_tm->tm_mday << 'T' <<
    std::setw(2) << now_ms % (24*60*60*1000) << ':' <<
    std::setw(2) << now_ms % (60*60*1000) << ':' <<
    std::setw(2) << now_ms % (60*1000) << '.' <<
    std::setw(3) << now_ms % (1000);
```

Although verbose, it is actually doing less than strftime.