# Create a new log file every time a connection is made on my tool in C++

Tags: c++

I need help with my log file. Every time I run the tool currently it gives logs on the same file, I need to add a code which can help me create a new file each time the connection is made.
Help would be extremely appreciated.

```
_mkdir(Path.c_str());

std::string FullFileName;
FullFileName.append(Path);
FullFileName.append(FileName);

::_sopen_s(&m_FileHandle, FullFileName.c_str(), _O_CREAT | _O_WRONLY | _O_BINARY, _SH_DENYWR, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
return m_FileHandle != -1 ? ::_lseek(m_FileHandle, 0, SEEK_END) : -1;
```

Comment: `...help me create a new file each` **time** `the connection is made`. There is a hint in your question that will solve your problem.

Comment: I do that with my logging. Make some part of the log file name contain the date and time of creation of the file.

Comment: Can't you add something unique to the filename? eg.: the time? So FileName+=time()

Comment: or just a counter.

Comment: @drescherjm does the log restart when you re run the file and gets saved to a new txt file?

Comment: Since the time has changed you will get a new filename each time the program is run.

Comment: Thats ok, can you share the code please? @drescherjm

Comment: There are many ways to get a timestamp into a std::string in this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527960/how-do-i-construct-an-iso-8601-datetime-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527960/how-do-i-construct-an-iso-8601-datetime-in-c) and this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927626/outputting-date-in-iso-8601-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927626/outputting-date-in-iso-8601-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
auto end=std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
FileName+=std::ctime(&time);
```

before `FullFileName.append(FileName);` Will add the time to the filename so it will be unique. (If you want to start it multiple times a second you can add miliseconds)

(also you have to `#include <chrono>`)