# How can I convert epoch time in microseconds to readable format

Tags: c++, c, bash, tcl

I have integer like this, 1522711404881438, it is the epoch time in microseconds. How can I convert it to human readable format, something like, `2018-04-03 11:22:33.123456`. My local time is GMT-7:00 time zone.

Thanks!

Comment: Eh, how about picking *one* language?

Comment: Have you looked at all at the library provided in <time.h>? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/time.h

Comment: Using C++, you can use the [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) library or [ctime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctime).

Comment: For Tcl, read http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm

Comment: May be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686846/get-current-time-in-milliseconds-or-hhmmssmmm-format/35157784#35157784

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you were looking for a bash answer, but you included that in your list of tags and it's pretty simple:

```
t=1522711404881438
date -d @${t%??????}
```

(Using BSD date, you want `date -jf %s {t%??????}`)

Given this `$t` and `TZ=PST8PDT`, this results in

> Mon Apr  2 16:23:24 PDT 2018

To get the format you want, specify it to date:

```
t=1522711404881438
date -d @${t%??????}.${t:10} +"%Y-%m-%d %T.%N"
```

> 2018-04-02 16:23:24.881438000

(This requires GNU date)

Answer (score 0):

In the shell:

```
date -d @1522711404881438
```

From javascript:

```js
console.log(new Date(1522711404881438).toLocaleString('fr-FR'))
console.log(new Date(1522711404881438).toLocaleString('en-US'))
```

Comment: The epoch date in the question is in microseconds, not seconds.  If you treat it as seconds, `date` presents the year as 48254773.

Comment: Ah thanks mate for precision.